# Error Truffle Console: web3.fromWei is not a function

Tags: truffle, truffle-console

I am executing commands from a tutorial at:

[JustDev Tutorial on Medium](https://medium.com/@JusDev1988/reentrancy-attack-on-a-smart-contract-677eae1300f2)

I am executing the command:

```
> truffle(ganache)> balanceInEth = address =>
> web3.fromWei(getBalance(address).toString())
```

I am getting the message:

> [Function: balanceInEth] truffle(ganache)>
> balanceInEth(victim.address) evalmachine.:0 balanceInEth =
> address => web3.fromWei(getBalance(address).toString())
> ^
>
> TypeError: web3.fromWei is not a function
> at balanceInEth (evalmachine.:0:32)
> at evalmachine.:0:1
> at sigintHandlersWrap (vm.js:98:15)
> at ContextifyScript.Script.runInContext (vm.js:56:12)
> at runScript (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:465120:21)

Somebody please guide me.

Zulfi.

Comment: You're probably on web3.js v1. Try `web3.utils.fromWei`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @goodvibration mentioned, you must be using web3.js v1
So you should use web3.utils.fromWei method instead
But you also need to use the await prefix before getBalance, because getBalance return a promise which fromWei doesn't understand
So my sugestion end up being like this

```
truffle(ganache)> web3.eth.getAccounts(function(err, acc) { accounts = acc });
truffle(ganache)> const boo = async () => { return web3.utils.fromWei(await web3.eth.getBalance(accounts[0]), 'ether'); }
truffle(ganache)> boo()
'99.0015542'
```

Comment: Hi @Luis Ricardo Sanchez, if I am using your commands I am getting error in the transaction:  >victim.deposit.sendTransaction(options)   truffle(development)> victim.deposit.sendTransaction(options)
Thrown:
{ Error: Returned error: from not found; is required
    at evalmachine.<anonymous>:0:16
    at sigintHandlersWrap (vm.js:288:15)
    at Script.runInContext (vm.js:130:14)
    at runScript (/home/zulfi/.nvm/versions/node/v10.22.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/core/lib/console.js:227:1)
    at Console.interpret (/home/zulfi/.nvm/versions/node/v10.22.0/li....Zulfi.